# Casperjs Google Login (V2) Not working

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs, google-signin

I´m using casperjs (so phantomjs in the middle) to access some google utilities but, before accessing them we should be logged in google. For V1 google authentication, we are using the following script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
url = 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount&followup=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&nojavascript=1#identifier';
casper.start(url, function() {

  this.fillSelectors('form#gaia_loginform', {
    'input[name="Email"]': 'your@email',
  }); //Fills the email box with email
  this.click("#next");

  this.wait(500, function() { //Wait for next page to load
    this.waitForSelector("#Passwd", //Wait for password box
      function success() {
        console.log("SUCCESS...");
        this.fillSelectors('form#gaia_loginform', {
          'input[name="Passwd"]': 'yourPassw',
        }); //Fill password box with PASSWORD
        this.click("#signIn"); //Click sign in button
        this.wait(500, function() {}); //Wait for it fully sigin
        casper.thenOpen('http://utility.google.com/', function() {
            this.wait(2000, function() {
                this.capture('media/status.png', undefined, {
                    format: 'png',
                    quality: 100`enter code here`
                });
            });
        });
      },
      function fail() {
        console.log("FAIL...");
      }
    );
  });
});
casper.run();
```

We have changed the way that we manipulate the form and fill the fields and It's working so far. The problem with V2 authentication is that triggering the mouse events isn't possible, that means we can't click using this.click("#next") and this.click("#signIn"). I tried doing post over the form, using different mouse events and also trying to manipulate directly the jsaction events. Nothing works.

Someone has an idea on how to solve this issue? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Casper use PhantomJS, and Phantom itself is unable to login in google account login. It seems to use any ES6 feature not supported in phantomjs it fails silently.

Maybe you can have more luck with beta phantomjs 2.5.
Anyway, phantomjs is deprecated in favor of chrome headless. As said by phantom maintainer Vitaly Slobodin
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/9aI5d-LDuNE

The good news is that you can start chrome in headless mode as: `/opt/google/chrome/chrome --headless --disable-gpu --repl` and do whatever you want.

You can replace the `--repl` with `--remote-debugging-port=9224` to control it in any remote code, like a program in node... 
There is libraries to control it like phantomjs.
High level (like phantom): https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer
and lower levels to have more control: https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface#clientdomainmethodparams-callback

Currently I had no luck with puppeteer but with chrome-remote-interface I was able to login in google account.

```
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
const file = require('fs');

// CLI Args
const url = argv.url || 'https://accounts.google.com';
const format = argv.format === 'jpeg' ? 'jpeg' : 'png';
const viewportWidth = argv.viewportWidth || 1440;
const viewportHeight = argv.viewportHeight || 900;
let delay = argv.delay || 0;
const userAgent = argv.userAgent;
const fullPage = argv.full;

// Start the Chrome Debugging Protocol
CDP(async function(client) {
  // Extract used DevTools domains.
  const {DOM, Emulation, Network, Page, Runtime} = client;

  // Enable events on domains we are interested in.
  await Page.enable();
  await DOM.enable();
  await Network.enable();

  // If user agent override was specified, pass to Network domain
  if (userAgent) {
    await Network.setUserAgentOverride({userAgent});
  }

  // Set up viewport resolution, etc.
  const deviceMetrics = {
    width: viewportWidth,
    height: viewportHeight,
    deviceScaleFactor: 0,
    mobile: false,
    fitWindow: false,
  };
  await Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride(deviceMetrics);
  await Emulation.setVisibleSize({width: viewportWidth, height: viewportHeight});

  // Navigate to target page
  await Page.navigate({url});

  // Wait for page load event to take screenshot
  Page.loadEventFired(async () => {
    // If the `full` CLI option was passed, we need to measure the height of
    // the rendered page and use Emulation.setVisibleSize
    if (fullPage) {
      const {root: {nodeId: documentNodeId}} = await DOM.getDocument();
      const {nodeId: bodyNodeId} = await DOM.querySelector({
        selector: 'body',
        nodeId: documentNodeId,
      });
      const {model: {height}} = await DOM.getBoxModel({nodeId: bodyNodeId});

      await Emulation.setVisibleSize({width: viewportWidth, height: height});
      // This forceViewport call ensures that content outside the viewport is
      // rendered, otherwise it shows up as grey. Possibly a bug?
      await Emulation.forceViewport({x: 0, y: 0, scale: 1});
    }

    let expr="document.querySelector('input[type=email]').value='YOUREMAIL@gmail.com';";
    expr+="document.querySelectorAll('div[role=button]')[0].click();";
    setTimeout
    let x=await Runtime.evaluate({expression: expr});
    console.log('******' + JSON.stringify(x));
    setTimeout(async function(){
    expr="document.querySelector('input[type=password]').value='YOUR_PASSWORD';";
    expr+="document.querySelectorAll('div[role=button]')[1].click()";
    x=await Runtime.evaluate({expression: expr});
    console.log('******' + JSON.stringify(x));
    x=await ( async function() {
            let expr="document.querySelector('input[type=password]')";
            return Runtime.evaluate({expression: expr});
    })()
    console.log('**' + JSON.stringify(x));
    }, 2000);
delay=5000
    setTimeout(async function() {
      const screenshot = await Page.captureScreenshot({format});
      const buffer = new Buffer(screenshot.data, 'base64');
      file.writeFile('output.png', buffer, 'base64', function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Screenshot saved');
        }
        client.close();
      });
    }, delay);
  });
}).on('error', err => {
  console.error('Cannot connect to browser:', err);
});
```

References:
https://medium.com/@dschnr/using-headless-chrome-as-an-automated-screenshot-tool-4b07dffba79a

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserwsendpoint

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Answer (score 0):

I also trying same and I found that the click is working with `this.click('#identifierNext');` and Google loaders start working. if you use following code after click to take screenshots you can see loader comes up but after that instead of going to Password screen it comes back to email screen.

Screenshot code

```
this.wait(200, function(){
    this.capture('1.jpg',{
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: 4608, 
        height: 3456,
        quality:20
    });
});
this.wait(100, function(){
    this.capture('2.jpg',{
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: 4608, 
        height: 3456,
        quality:20
    });
});
this.wait(100, function(){
    this.capture('3.jpg',{
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: 4608, 
        height: 3456,
        quality:20
    });
});
this.wait(100, function(){
    this.capture('4.jpg',{
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: 4608, 
        height: 3456,
        quality:20
    });
});
```

But I am also not able to reach Password screen, if with this help you can come with any idea let me know.